# Can't get javascript to modify a header

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, submit

This code is supposed to ask the user for an input and return incorrect or correct depending on the string that was submitted(the correct answer is "Aconcagua"). When running it and submitting neither of those answers is printed into the screen. I am pretty new to javascript and HTML.

```js
function wrong2()
                {
        document.querySelector('#2solution').innerHTML = "Incorrect.";
        document.querySelector('#input').style.backgrounColor = 'red';
}
function right2()
                {
        document.querySelector('#2solution').innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.querySelector('#input').style.backgrounColor = 'green';
}

a = "Aconcagua";
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    if (document.querySelector('#input').value.localeCompare(a) == 0)
    {
        right2();
    }
    else
    {
        wrong2();
    }

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Trivia!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
        <hr>
        <h3>What is the highest mountain in South America?</h3>
        <form action="" id="form">
            <input id="input" type="text">
            <button id="b" type="sumbit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <h2 id="2solution"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: In order to call a function you need the parenthesis behind the function name eg `right2;` needs to be `right2();` but also note your script is running before the form element exists so your listener isnt going to be set

Comment: You should be getting an error  in the console from `document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener(...)`

Comment: You should always have the console open when you're debugging JavaScript.

Comment: Do you know about using your browser's devtools inspect facility?

Comment: @Santiago I made a snippet out of your code, removed the extra </div> and indented your code for a better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code. First you have a closing "/div" without an opening "div". You also have a typo on BackgroundColor (witout d). It is better to define const in the beginning of your javascript (unless sometimes necessary). Also open full page to see colored background when using snippet. Besides these errors your code could have worked :-)

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form')
const solutionDisplay = document.querySelector('#solution')
const inputField = document.querySelector('#input')
console.log(inputField)
let a = "Aconcagua";

function wrong2(){
        solutionDisplay.innerHTML = "Incorrect.";
        inputField.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
function right2(){
        solutionDisplay.innerHTML = "Correct!";
        inputField.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}


form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        if(inputField.value == a){
                right2();
        }
        else{
                wrong2()
        }
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
            <hr>
            <h3>What is the highest mountain in South America?</h3>
            <form action="" id="form">
                <input id="input" type="text">
                <button id="b" type="sumbit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h2 id="solution"></h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a question, how does this code solve the fact that when the script runs in the header the form does no exist yet? I saw you didn't write ```document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){``` anywhere, how does this work?

Comment: Ok first your code is always read from top to bottom.  So you always need to put javascript at the end of your HTML after the body tag example) (or in the head of your HTML but with defer attribute to make it run after HTML). Because as you use DOM element you need them to be already placed before calling them with javascript. And no worry with some training all this will be very familiar to you !

Comment: Ex if you put javascript on top of your HTML code and you call the h2 with id="solution" you will get error because javascript will be running and calling for something (DOM) that does not already exists

Comment: ok so how could I implement this code to put it in the head of my html?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parentheses () which are necessary to call the functions. right2() and wrong2().
Without (), they are just treated as references to the functions rather than function calls.

Corrected code:

```
<script>
    function wrong2() {
        document.querySelector('#2solution').innerHTML = "Incorrect.";
        document.querySelector('#input').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }

    function right2() {
        document.querySelector('#2solution').innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.querySelector('#input').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }

    // Function for event listener
    function setUpEventListener() {
    a = "Aconcagua";
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit',function(event){
console.log("Input value:",document.querySelector('#input').value);

if (document.querySelector('#input').value === a) {
    right2(); // Correct answer
} else {
    wrong2(); // Incorrect answer
}
event.preventDefault();
});
    }

    // Ensure the event listener is set up after the form element exists
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        setUpEventListener();
    });
</script>
```

The DOMContentLoaded fires only once the HTML page has been fully parsed, so this ensures your form has loaded before the event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I made those corrections but the code still does not output the line as the function says, could it be that the comparison with ```a``` is wrong? I'm not sure

Comment: @SantiagoDeLuca, okay, I made some changes, could you console.log the input value to see if it matches and is being displayed? Also removed localeCompare and went with strict inequality (===).

Comment: I am testing it but it still does not work, I am quite new to javascript, what is console.log?

Comment: So when you right click on your website, the inspect element? console.log is used to output values to the console that's in the inspect element. It is a useful tool to debug, in this case, we are outputting the input value to see if it's working. 

[Console Log](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/dont-understand-the-purpose-of-console-log/249230/2)

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I don't understand where exactly I should run console.log, should i run it when I hit inspect the website? when inspecting i don't see any errors, just the code to my html.

Comment: I solved the problem, apparently in javascript variable names CANNOT start with a number. And my variable was called ```2solution```. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perfect yes exactly I remeber removing the number 2. For adding javascrript code eitherwithin a script tag at the end of your HTML between body and HTML tag, or in a different file script.js in the same folder as your HTML file for example then you need to link it to your HTML file in the head tag using <script src="script.js" defer></script>